# Using templates in Libraries

Tags: c++, templates, linker, shared-libraries

### Setup

**a.h**

```
void foo(void);
```

**a.cc**

```
#include "a.h"
void foo(void) { /* do something */ }
```

These both are compiled to a shared library called `libA`

**b.h**

```
#include "a.h"

void bar(void);
template <typename T>
void baz(void)
{
    foo();
}
```

**b.cc**

```
#include "b.h"

void bar(void)
{
    foo();
}
```

These two get compiled to the shared library `libB`, and are linked against `libA`.

Now I write my main program, which is linked against `libB`, but *not* `libA`.

**main.cc**

```
#include "b.h"

int main(void)
{
    bar();  // Okay, compiles
    baz<int>();  // Undefined symbol *foo()*, referenced from void bar<int>() in main-(...)
}
```

---

### Explanation

I kinda get, why this throws up an error. In `libB` I have a template declaration, which can be used to instantiate functions, although it doesn't instantiate any in `libB` itself.

In `main.cc` however it instantiates the function `void bar<int>(void)`, which is then placed in the object code for `main.cc`, where it can't find `libA`s `foo()` function and throws the linking error.

And who would have thought? If I link `main.cc` against `libB` as well, it works just fine.

*My question is however*: How can I work with templates efficiently, without without having to link against the original library and/or having to instantiate every single version of `bar<>()`, that I intend to use?

---

### EDIT - clarification from chat

The goal is to allow libB to provide templates, without requiring explicit instantiation in libB, and without the client being coupled to libB's implementation details.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense - is `bar` supposed to be the template or `baz`? Currently you have an un-implemented template called `bar` (with a private non-template overload in the .cc), and a non-template `baz` which should be declared inline.

Comment: Oh yeah, and - why can't `main.o(bj)` find `foo` from `libA`? It already depends on `libB`, which in turn depends on `libA`. Perhaps this is platform-dependent?

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it. I'm leaving out the inline for simplicity.

Comment: @Useless `bar()` can find `foo()`, `baz()` can't. Also notice they are shared libraries, not static.

Comment: Why? The header is visible, and your `main` has a transitive dependency on `libA`. Again, platform please. This seems like it should work fine on POSIX/*NIX etc, but I know some platforms have odd ideas about shared libraries.

Comment: OS X, but I already explained below, that when I link `main.cc` against `libA`, it works. I think the reason is that the template function is not compiled, after all it's part of the header.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106382/discussion-between-useless-and-hgiesel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template definitions are part of the *public* interface of your library (libB, in this case).

The only way to decouple a client of libB from its implementation details (in this case: the dependency on libA), is the usual: don't make them public. Hide them inside libB. If they're visible in b.h, they're part of the public interface.

The simple solution in this case is to provide a (non-template, non-inline) function in libB which abstracts the dependency on libA:

---

```
// b.h
void do_fooish_things();

template <typename T>
void baz(void)
{
    do_fooish_things();
}
```

---

```
// b.cc
#include <libA/a.h>
void do_fooish_things() {
    // hidden implementation detail
    libA::foo();
}
```